Site logo background isn't transparent, looks funny if hidden in network profile
I was experimenting with the new ability to hide sites from the network profile and noticed that, while most sites I hid were cleanly grayed out, Crypto had an ugly white background frame around the logo. Seemingly, there's a lack of transparency in http://cdn.sstatic.net/crypto/img/icon-48.png.

Security by obscurity is bad*, so let's fix that!
*I couldn't resist.

We're working on fix. Thanks for reporting.

Certainly, but here is what happen when the background is transparent.

See here : http://stackexchange.com/sites# (click on the Crypto tile)

Yeah, that's tricky. Looks like either framing that one in white, or using the same trick the actual site design uses (color reversing the outermost layers) would do the job there. There's probably something about reusing the apple-touch-icon along with using the darkest site color that's making things trickier there.

The same as main issue - fix for this is in progress.
